# How to execute functions in Live editor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I recently started using Live editor in MATLAB and I inserted a function inside it. But, apparently, I cannot execute that particular section of code where I type function. Even the section break disappears. 
Is it that using function is not suitable for live editor?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the MATLAB parser did not join the 20th century until partway through 2016, and **could not interpret function definitions in scripts (live or otherwise) until R2016b**. In the web-based docs, there is a notice at [Add Functions to Scripts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html), but it took me a while to find this out because the builtin docs in R2016a or earlier do not explicitly contain this information. It is implied by the tutorials that tell you to create a new file for each function (which to me, a python programmer, sounds more like strange advice than a restriction).

Trying to define a function in a live script gives confusing errors. For example, if you create a cell with this content:

```
function y = myfunc(x)
    y = 2*x;
end
```

It will underline the keyword `function` with a popup error that reads:

> Parse error at FUNCTION: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.

*Might* be? Whom shall I ask? Upon running the cell, it prints an error after the first line:

> All functions in a script must be closed with an `end`.

I eventually made this discovery myself thanks to a helpful message if the first thing you happen to do in a new empty live script is to start typing `function` on the first line; as soon as you hit the spacebar a message pops up at the top saying:

> Functions and classes are not supported in the Live Editor. To continue, save the file as a plain text code file (`.m`).

Answer (score 0):

It should work as when you add a function inside a script. For example, like this:

[image]

What function are you exactly trying to code?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. That exact cell gives an error "All functions in a script must be closed with an `end`." What version are you using?